# How to interpret the text of this exercise: find formulas for the following implicitly functions

Tags: functions

I have some issues in the interpretation of this exercise:

> **Find formulas for the following implicitly deﬁned functions**. What are their domains and ranges?
>
> $y = f(x)$ is the solution of equation $x^{3}y + 2y = 5$.

I have put only this function, without listing the others, as my question is just about the interpretation of the exercise; in particular, the interpretation of the part in bold.

What does the exercise ask? Does it ask that I perform some algebraic manipulations in order to render the function explicit? I am slightly perplexed as it speaks about finding formulas... does it mean the same I am saying?

EDIT:

Ok, although it looks simple, I proceed with the steps in order to have further confirmation from you that I interpret the exercise well. So, should be like this:

x^3*y + 2y = 5

I multiply both sides of the equation by 1/y, in order to simplify y on a side, with the result that I will have isolated y at the denominator of the other side.

1/y * y(x^3 + 2) = 5 / y which becomes x^3 + 2 = 5 / y

y = 5 / x^3 + 2

At this point, I guess I have to find domain and range of the function, now in its explicit form (if I did not do mistakes). I don't think I will have problems in finding domain and range...

PS. Yet, the text doesn't look so well written to me: "Find formulas for the following implicitly deﬁned functions. What are their domains and ranges". The word formula confuses me. I don't think that it is so correct to say that with my algebraic manipulation I have found a formula...or am I wrong?

EDIT: I would be happy to get a second answer which confirms what I state after - or, alike, if who already answered can confirm further or retreat after my edits.

Comment: It asks you to express $y$ in terms of $x$. Note that not every $x$ will do.

Comment: According to what you wrote, I can guess what is intended to that extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your manipulation is slightly dangerous: dividing both sides by $y$ excludes $y=0$ from the solution. Actually $y$ can't be zero in *this* excercise, however in general this is unsafe.
A better way is excluding a common term:
$$x^3y + 2y = 5$$
$$(x^3 + 2)y = 5$$
and then dividing by what you need to remove:
$$y = \frac 5{x^3 + 2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are supposed to do algebraic manipulations to have the left side $y$ and the right side not contain $y$.  The reason it is called "implicitly defined" is that $x$ and $y$ are both on the same side of the equation, so you cannot (easily) plug in a value for $x$ and find $y$.  This will also make it easier to read off what values of $x$ are acceptable.